# Lebesgue integral, path connected and compact

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ be path-connected and compact and $f:K\to\mathbb R$ continuous. How can I show that there is a $\xi\in K$ such that $$\int_Kfd\lambda^d=f(\xi)\lambda^d(K)$$ where $\lambda^d$ denotes the Lebesgue-measure on $\mathbb R^d$.

Some ideas and hints would be appreciated, or maybe a hint on which theorems I should review.

Comment: Are you sure that $f$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^d$? How is the integral defined then?

Comment: oh thanks, typo, fixed hehe :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m = \inf \limits_{x \in K} f(x)$ and $M = \sup \limits_{x \in K} f(x)$. Now

$$m \, \lambda^d(K) \leq  \int_K f \mathrm{d} \lambda^d \leq M\,\lambda^d(K).$$
Now, since $K$ is compact, there are $x_m, x_M \in K$ such that $f(x_m)=m$ and $f(x_M)=M$. Since $f$ is continuous and $K$ is connected, $f$ attains all values between $m$ and $M$. The claim follows.

Comment: Maybe! That would be a simple solution just making use of the intermediate value theorem. I am not too familiar with Lebesgue integrals yet, how do I have to interpret $\int_K f \mathrm{d} \lambda^d$ I need to understand that first in order to understand that $m \, \lambda^d(K) \leq  \int_K f \mathrm{d} \lambda^d$

Comment: Let $f,g: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$, with $g(x) \leq f(x)$. Then the Lebesgue integral satisfies the natural inequality $\int_{A} g \leq \int_{A} f$ for all measurable $A$. Taking $g = \inf_A f$ you have the inequality I wrote there.

Comment: Yes but why isn't it $  \int_Km\lambda^d \leq  \int_K f \mathrm{d} \lambda^d \leq \int_KM\,\lambda^d.$ then

Comment: It is! But: $\int_K m \lambda^d = m \int_K1 \lambda^d = m \lambda^d(K)$.

Comment: Yes I'm too simple-minded. Thank you!